# How to make :hover not work on mobile screens in @media?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to remove the `:hover` action on the mobile screen in the @media request.

Sample code:

```
.podcasts {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #121723
}

.podcasts:hover {
  color: #ff0000;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  -o-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

<a href="#lala" class="podcasts">podcast</a>
```

I found a solution: write `:hover` separately in @media, and not in general styles. But I'm not sure that this is the right way to solve it. Are there other ways to do that?

Sample code the solution I found:

```
@media (min-width: 1050px) { 
 .podcasts: hover { 
  color: #ff0000;
 }
}
```

Comment: you dont need to remove it? mobile does not know the `:hover` state

Comment: You don't need vendor prefixes for transition. See https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_transition.

Comment: @Xiduzo 
In the mobile version, cursor hover styles work. This doesn't work the way it does in the desktop version when the cursor is hovered over, it works when a link or button is clicked, resulting in the hovering of the cursor being saved for the element. Therefore, I need to remove hover for mobile screens whose resolution is 760px/320px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to apply a hover effect to an element on a website, you can use CSS to style the element when the user hovers over it with their mouse cursor. However, on mobile devices, there is no mouse cursor, so the hover effect needs to be triggered by touch instead.

To apply a hover effect that works on only for desktop devices, you can use CSS media queries to apply the hover effect only on screens with a minimum width, such as 1050 pixels. This ensures that the hover effect is only applied on larger screens where a mouse cursor is present.

```
@media (min-width: 1050px) {
  .podcasts:hover {
    color: #ff0000;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to define `hover` for the specific media (in this case the mobile).

However, `hover` is not working on mobile device so you can even leave as it is in the general style.

Comment: In the mobile version, cursor hover styles work. This doesn't work the way it does in the desktop version when the cursor is hovered over, it works when a link or button is clicked, resulting in the hovering of the cursor being saved for the element.

Comment: Yes it works. When you click, it show the effect